# How can I open a Tweet page from an Android app?

Tags: android, api, twitter

I want to open a Tweet's page from my Android app.
I have tried this:

`startActivity(Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("twitter://status?status_id=[tweet_ID]")))`

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow!
What happens when you try?

Answer (score 0):

**Hi, you could create a sample application using the WebView.**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webview;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        webview =(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView);

        webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.setOverScrollMode(WebView.OVER_SCROLL_NEVER);
        webview.loadUrl("https://www.google.com");

    }
```

**In your Android manifest request the permission to use INTERNET**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

**Inside your layout, we need to create the web view.**

```
<WebView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
```

If you want to learn more about webview here is the documentation link 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView